# How to clear the data for a angular-chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I have a nice application that displays a line chart based on several criteria. When the main criteria is changed I want to clear the current line chart. However, I cannot find out how to do this. I'm using AngulerJS v1.4.0-rc2, Chart.js v1.0.2 and angular-chart v0.7.1.

When loading the page I call the function `updateSelection()`. This function is also called when any of the other criteria changes. The function is implemented as:

```
$scope.updateSelection = function() {
    $scope.chartLabels = maandData;
    if ($scope.isPostcodeArea()) {
        $scope.chartSeries = getPostcodeSeries();
        $scope.chartData = getPostcodeData($scope.dataArea.index, $scope.dataMetric.index);
    } else {
        $scope.chartSeries = getSelectionSeries();
        $scope.chartData = getSelectionData($scope.dataArea.index, $scope.dataMetric.index);
    }
};
```

This will call the proper functions to initialize the data for the line chart based on the main criteria. Displaying the data entries in the web page shows the correct values.

In the select box for the main criteria I call the function `updateArea()`:

```
$scope.updateArea = function() {
    $scope.form.$setPristine();
    if ($scope.isPostcodeArea()) {
        $scope.postcodeSelection = null;
        $scope.postcodeCompare1 = null;
        $scope.postcodeCompare2 = null;
        $scope.postcodeCompare3 = null;
    } else {
        $scope.selectionData = null;
        $scope.selectionCompare1 = null;
        $scope.selectionCompare2 = null;
        $scope.selectionCompare3 = null;
    }
    $scope.selections = getSelections($scope.dataArea.index);
    $scope.selectionLabel = $scope.areas[$scope.dataArea.index].label;
    $scope.chartLabels = [];
    $scope.chartSeries = [];
    $scope.chartData = [];
};
```

This function will reset the input form and the form data. It will also determine the data for another criteria (`selections`), a label appropriate for the criteria (`selectionLabel`) and it should reset the chart data.

However, the chart is not updated to reflect the new data. So, is there a way to reset the data properly?

The chart itself is displayed using the following HTML:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line"
    data="chartData" labels="chartLabels" series="chartSeries"
    legend="true" options="{'scaleBeginAtZero': true, 'datasetFill': false}">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem and found two ways to solve it

The first way is getting the context for the canvas and using clearRect function:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('line');
if (canvas){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}
```

This way you can clear the canvas, no matter if your data is still set. Doing it like this I had a problem with hover event, when I moved my mouse over it, the canvas was seted with the data again. So I looked for another way to do it.

The second way you can try is using ChartJsProvider:

<strike>1.- In the createChart function in your angular-chart.js file, add this line just after the variable chart initialization:</strike>

```
var chart = new ChartJs.Chart(ctx)[type](data, options);
ChartJs.createdChart = chart; // add this line so you can access chart variable from ChartJsProvider
```

2.- Inject ChartJs to the Controller

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['ChartJs'];

function MyController(ChartJs){
    // your controller code
}
```

3.- In your controller use the createdChart destroy function to clear/destroy the chart

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('line');
if (canvas) { 
    ChartJs.createdChart.destroy();
}
```

This way is working for me correctly in chrome, opera, and safari.

Edited:

I found a new way to do this better than modifying the library (I know it's not a good practice so that's why I tried to find this new way)

You still need to inject ChartJs to the Controller

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['ChartJs'];

function MyController(ChartJs){
    // your controller code
}
```

I created a function called clearChart with a parameter elementId so if you have more than one chart in your page you can access directly to the one you want to clear/remove:

```
function clearChart(elementId) {
    if (document.getElementById(elementId)) {
        var charts = ChartJs.Chart.instances; // Get all chart instances
        for (var key in charts){ // loop looking for the chart you want to remove
            if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                continue;
            }
            var chartAux = ChartJs.Chart.instances[key]; 
            if (chartAux.chart.ctx.canvas.id === elementId){ 
                // Remove chart-legend before destroying the chart
                var parent = chartAux.chart.ctx.canvas.parentElement;
                var legend = chartAux.chart.ctx.canvas.nextElementSibling;
                parent.removeChild(legend);
                // Compare id with elementId passed by and if it is the one            
                // you want to remove just call the destroy function
                ChartJs.Chart.instances[key].destroy(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This new second way works perfectly for me.

I hope it helps and sorry about my english

Comment: Thanks! The second option works like a charm. I now have to add some code to hide the legend as well but that should be peanuts.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped you. To remove the legend I use DOM elements. I've just updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found another method that's working better for me and it is done with less code.

Chart.js is emitting an `onCreate` event in it you're getting the created chart object.

Then I'm storing the object in a variable so I can use it in my click handler.
(If you're having multiple charts on your page you probably get multiple `onCreate` events and you could store each chart object in an array or object for later usage.)

In the click handler you can call `lineChart.destroy()` and that will destroy your chart object. Don't forget to clear your data too. The chart will be re-created by angular-chartjs if you need it again.

The benefit of this is that everything is resetted. I had the issue before that the x-axis scale wasn't cleared with other methods.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/1e8ds6ja/).

One issue that I need to check in my demo is that the chart is completely regenerate at every new data. Maybe this is normal behaviour but I'm not sure.

```js
angular.module('chartDemo', ['chart.js'])
 .config(['ChartJsProvider', function (ChartJsProvider) {
    // Configure all charts
    ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
      animation: false,
      colours: ['#FF5252', '#FF8A80'],
      //responsive: false
    });
    // Configure all line charts
    ChartJsProvider.setOptions('Line', {
      //datasetFill: false
      //legendTemplate: /*'<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><button ng-click="mainCtrl.toggle()">test</button><span style="background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'*/
    });
  }])
 .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope, $timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  var defaultData = [
      [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
   ],
    lineChart; //created in onCreate
  
  angular.extend(vm, {
   series: ['Series A'], 
   data: defaultData,
    labels: Object.keys(defaultData[0]),
   onClick: function (points, evt) {
     console.log(points, evt);
   },
    enable: true,
    onChange: function() {
      if ( vm.enable )
       startTimer();
    },
    clear: function() {
      console.log('clear chart');
      vm.data = [[]];
      lineChart.destroy();
    },
    startTimer: startTimer,
    toggle: function() {
      consoel.log('Test')
    }
  });
 
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    // not working yet
    console.log('test');
  };
  
  $scope.$on('toggle', function(e, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  
  //console.log(Object.keys(defaultData[0]));
  
  function startTimer() {
    if ( vm.enable ) {
     $timeout(function() {
          vm.data[0].push(Math.random()*50);
          startTimer();
          vm.labels = Object.keys(vm.data[0])
       }, 500);
    }
  }
  
  if (vm.enable) startTimer();
  
  $scope.$on('create', function (event, chart) {
   console.log(chart);
    lineChart = chart;
 });
}

MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/master/dist/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alanszp/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/master/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="chartDemo" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
  enable<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mainCtrl.enable" ng-change="mainCtrl.startTimer();"/><button ng-click="mainCtrl.clear()">Clear</button>
    <canvas id="line" 
      class="chart chart-line" chart-data="mainCtrl.data" 
      chart-labels="mainCtrl.labels" 
      chart-legend="true" chart-series="mainCtrl.series" chart-legend="true"
      chart-click="mainCtrl.onClick"></canvas> 
  <pre>{{mainCtrl.debug}}</pre>
</div>
```